# Displaying notifications from Ionic using cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

We are developing an application using the Ionic Framework and would like to integrate push notifications. We are currently attempting to use the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging to handle notifications on Android and iOS. I can see that onMessage is being called when I send a notification but how do I make the notification actually display? At the moment I am just trying to log the response by using

```
this.fcm.onMessage()
   .subscribe(payload => {
      console.log(payload);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ionic, you can make easy popups with either [AlertController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',
    subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Or [toastController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/toast/ToastController/)

```
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController) {

}

presentToast() {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'User was added successfully',
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  });

  toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
    console.log('Dismissed toast');
  });

  toast.present();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have this issue on iOS? If so then it's not a bug. You won't see any notification on iOS devices if the app is running in foreground.

> **From Apple:** If you receive local or remote notifications while your app is running
>   in the foreground, you’re responsible for passing the information to
>   your users in an app-specific way

Comment: Actually its on Android. After playing around with it some more I think the same thing may be true on Android, at least with this plugin. Thank you though for the information about iOS as we will be deploying to iOS as well in the future. I would gather then the best thing to do is create some kind of in app popup to display the information from the notification.